# Не выводится картинка в pdf-документе в ларавел (barryvdh\dompdf laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, изображения, pdf

Решаю проблему вывода изображения в pdf-документе средствами dompdf в ларавел 9. При генерации pdf-документа, вместо картинки пишется текст "Image not found or type unknown". Читал советы [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690599/laravel-dompdf-error-image-not-found-or-type-unknown) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65879112/image-not-found-or-type-unknown-barryvdh-dompdf-laravel). Не помогли советы. Прописал в контроллере следующее:

```
    $arr_house = ['0' => $house];
    view()->share('house',$arr_house);
    $PDFOptions = ['isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true, 'isRemoteEnabled' => true];
    $pdf = PDF::setOptions($PDFOptions)->loadView('house.pdf', $arr_house);
    $id = $house->id;
    return $pdf->download("pdf_file_".$id.".pdf");
```

В шаблоне blade house.pdf вывожу картинку следующим образом:

```
<img src="<?=public_path().'/storage/app/public/'.$house[0]->foto_main;?>" width="450px"/>
```

Вместо картинки появляется крест и надпись на английском языке. Как решить проблему с картинкой?

Comment: Изображение должно быть доступно по пути, указанном в src, если его вбить в браузер. У вас оно доступно?